# jquery toggle with on

Tags: jquery, click

I thought I saw somewhere you could do something like this in jQuery

```
$(".show").on("click", function(){
  alert('1st');
}, function() {
  alert('2nd');
});
```

where the first click would call the fist one, a 2nd click the 2nd one and a 3rd back to the first one. I know that this particular sample doesn't work, but is there a similar way to toggle click behavior in jQuery?

Comment: this will always fire `alert('2nd')` : http://jsfiddle.net/5ZCyx/

Comment: Not like that. You would have to keep track of the number times the user clicked and check the value in your click function.

Comment: What are you asking?  What are you wanting to do?  http://sscce.org

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/#on1

Comment: `.on` does no support multiple callbacks like that (see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). You would need to create a single callback function with some basic logic to alternate between the two results.

Comment: for live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/4EhMj/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.show').addClass('OddClick');

            $('.show').live('click', function () {
                var obj = $(this);

                if (obj.hasClass('OddClick') === true) {
                    obj.addClass('EvenClick').removeClass('OddClick');
                    alert('1st');
                }
                else {
                    obj.addClass('OddClick').removeClass('EvenClick');
                    alert('2nd');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="show" style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bolder; cursor: pointer;">
        Hello World
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You can acheive this behavior using the [toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) in jQuery. It will cause each successive click to cycle through the callbacks you provide. In your case, you can do this:

```
$(".show").toggle(function(){ 
  alert('1st'); 
}, function() { 
  alert('2nd'); 
});
```

You can provide an arbitrary number of callbacks to cycle through if you like

```
$(".show").toggle(function(){ 
  alert('1st'); 
}, function() { 
  alert('2nd'); 
}, function(){
  alert('3rd');
});
```

You can see this in action on this [jsFiddle demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/BqrN5/).